# Edit Windows Registry to turn off Outlook Calendar Feature: "Shorten appointments and meetings"

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, calendar

Is there a way to edit the windows registry to turn off the Outlook Calendar Feature: "Shorten appointments and meetings"? I don't want my meetings to automatically end early but I am unable to uncheck the grayed-out box.

Thanks

Comment: Is this in an enterprise environment or your personal computer and accounts? Enterprise admins can set this globally, and your not being able to change this manually in the settings indicates that there is a good chance that is what is going on here.

Comment: Yes, this is an enterprise environment. Would there be a way to edit the registry to change the setting?

I create many meeting notices for my own purposes to track my work, and it is annoying to have to change each event to the full half hour or full hour. When creating a meeting with other team members, I can manually adjust to the "normal" time reduction which I believe was put in place to allow team members to take breaks.

Thanks

Comment: No, modern device management will simply reset those, or ignore them. If you need to be exempted from this policy, you need to speak with your IT support staff who are able to do this. Also, please note that because your IT staff are responsible for making this setting, controlling your device, and making sure that your work devices meet your work needs, questions about corporate IT are mostly off topic on this site, and this question is not one of the exception cases.